# getTextSize() always returns 1.0 for fragment TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am doing Robolectric testing on an app. (Robolectric 2.1 with ABS). In my fragment, I have a TextView with style:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/homepage_title_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/loading_textview_padding_top"
        android:text="@string/loading_homepage_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
```

Anytime that I try:

```
TextView homepageTitle = (TextView) mFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.homepage_title_textview);  
float textSize = homepageTitle.getTextSize();
```

It always returns 1.0. I have tested that the TextView has been created and visible with:

```
assertThat(homepageTitle.getVisibility(), equalTo(View.VISIBLE));
```

I have also changed the whole `style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"` line to be `android:textSize="18sp"` instead to see if it would make a difference and it does not.

If it helps, here is my exact Robolectric test:

```
int style = android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium; 
int[] attrWanted = {android.R.attr.textSize};
TypedArray styleValues = Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext().obtainStyledAttributes(style, attrWanted);
String wantedTextSize = styleValues.getString(0);
String actualTextSize = String.valueOf(myTextView.getTextSize());
```

wantedTextSize returns "18sp"
actualTextSize returns "1.0"

Answer (score 0):

I believe to get the text size of the textview.

```
String textSize = homepageTitle.getTextSize();
```

For that, you must specify a size

```
style="android:textSize="18sp""
```

does not qualify. But

```
android:textSize="18sp"
```

will qualify.

Hope this works.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my original question. I actually mean that I replaced the whole `style=""` line with: `android:textSize="18sp"` so that will not matter. It still gave me 1.0. Edited original question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure getTextSize() returns a float :P

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize%28%29)

Use:

```
float textSize = homepageTitle.getTextSize();
```

Comment: You're right that is a mistake on my part in the question. My program has that line. I added my exact implementation above in original question.